# Icosahedron joining edge angles

Tags: math, language-agnostic

Consider a regular icosahedron. Even with my poor math skills it is fairly easy to generate with code when you realise that the vertices of an icosahedron are the corners of three orthogonal rectangles:

[image: Icosahedron]

I would like to extend the faces but still make them join seamlessly together.
Sort of like this.
[image: example]

With my puny trigonometry skills this is what I am thinking.
pseudo code

```
var triangles = 20;
var seams = triangles*3;
var targetAngle = 360/seams; //6 degrees.
```

Is this the correct way to go about it?

ps: if you are interested in some code to generate a icosahedron and icosphere here is a nice article. http://blog.andreaskahler.com/2009/06/creating-icosphere-mesh-in-code.html

Comment: Are you asking what happens if you add a triangular prism on each face of a regular icosahedron? If so, the angle would just be the angle between the normal vectors of two adjacent sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is the dihedral angle. These are well know and you can see a table at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_polyhedron_dihedral_angles .
For an Icosahedron the angle is π − arccos(√5/3) or approximately 138.19°.
The angle in your diagram is 360° - 138.19° - 90° - 90° = 41.81°.